# How can I sort by realtime score in solr?

Tags: solr

Now I have a solr collection: question

question has some field:

```
id
answer_count
created_at
updated_at
```

now I have the sort rule:

```
score = answer_count * 100 - (the hours now to created_at) * 5
```

then I need to sort by the score desc.

how can i do that because of the score is realtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key for this are function queries. Assumed you use EDisMaxQP, you can specify a boost function (`bf`) with this value:

`sub(product(answer_count,100),product(div(ms(NOW,created_at),3600000),5))`

However, a function query would *influence* scoring, but it rather looks like you don’t want any scoring at all and instead a fixed sort order, so I guess it’s rather a case of using this as value of `sort`:

`sub(product(answer_count,100),product(div(ms(NOW,created_at),3600000),5)) desc`

Of course, boosting newer documents [is in the FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents) and you could have found out this for yourself.